# Obtener registros en un rango de fecha DB2

Tags: sql, select, db2

mi intención es obtener datos (DB2) de varios días hacia atrás, incluyendo el actual, ya que al indicar `CURRENT DATE -2 DAYS`, solo obtendría lo que se genero hace 2 días, y la idea es obtener lo de hoy, ayer y ante ayer, favor vuestra ayuda

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE DATE(fecha_creacion) = CURRENT DATE
```

Answer (score 1):

Usas `BETWEEN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE DATE(fecha_creacion)
BETWEEN DATE('2018-01-01') AND DATE('2018-01-31');
```

que para tu caso, podría ser algo como

```
SELECT *
FROM tabla
WHERE DATE(fecha_creacion)
BETWEEN CURRENT DATE AND CURRENT DATE -2 DAYS;
```

Tengo dudas sobre la segunda parte de la expresión pero pues, nunca he usado DB2 :)